# Print selection cursors index in JetBrains' IDEs

Tags: jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to access the index of the cursors when multiple selection cursors are active?

Example :

Say I had the following text, with 5 cursors

```
lo|rem
ip|sum
do|lor
si|t
am|et
```

With access to the index of the cursors, I could easily make turn it into

```
lo1rem
ip2sum
do3lor
si4t
am5et
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a plugin by simply iterating over each caret/cursor from `getCaretModel().getAllCarets()` and inserting a running index. The `getAllCarets()` method always returns carets sorted by visual order:

```java
public class CaretIndexAction extends AnAction {
    public CaretIndexAction() {
        super("Insert Caret Index(es)");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
        Editor editor = PlatformDataKeys.EDITOR.getData(event.getDataContext());
        Document doc = editor.getDocument();

        WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(event.getProject(), () -> {
            int i = 1;
            for (Caret c : editor.getCaretModel().getAllCarets()) {
                doc.replaceString(c.getSelectionStart(), c.getSelectionEnd(), String.valueOf(i));
                i++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: As a developer I like that you went the "built it yourself" way, but I was thinking on the lines of tools that are built-in the the IDE itself. I remember being able to do it on Sublime Text, through Search and Replace and RegEx and text manipulation shortcuts only.